# Notify all components that authentication has been changed in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor (version `net5.0`) component with a lot of `html` markups and here is some part of it :

```
<a class="@(IsAuthenticated?"":"hide")" href="#">My link for logged in users</a>
```

and here is my c# code (**MyComponent.Razor**):

```
    [CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationState { get; set; }
    private AuthenticationState auth;
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        auth = await authenticationState;
        var user = auth.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
```

and in my **Login component** after successful login I call `StateHasChanged();`

```
  void Login()
  {
    ...
    StateHasChanged();
  }
```

But after login no changes to MyComponent will be applied unless I refresh the page so the component rerender itself.

**Note:** I don't want to use `AuthorizeView` because as I mentioned there are lots of markups and components in the **MyComponent** and I don't want to have an `AuthorizeView` for every style or element that I want to change their behaviors based on user's authentication.

**Update:** I have the following code in my `App.razor` component:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout)" >
            <Authorizing>
                <text> my Custom Authotizing in app.razor ...</text>
            </Authorizing> 
            <NotAuthorized>
                <text> my Custom NOT Authotized in app.razor ...</text>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Layout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: Another example why the Blazor tag must not be allowed. OP should always state what flavor of Blazor he's using

Comment: @enet Stand-alone WebAssembly with no host

Comment: @enet I don't use OIDC or IdentyServer4. I think when user Authenticate(no matter how) the components should be notified.

Comment: @enet thank you.  I use Jwt token authentication. And it works fine. the AuthorizeView is also works fine.

Comment: @enet No I didn't solve the problem I just meant that my other parts of my code has not problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `AuthorizedView` source code I finally figured out that I should use `OnParametersSetAsync` and a property :

```
<a class="@MyClassProp" href="#">My link for logged in users</a>
```

code:

```
public string MyClassProp { get; set; } = "hide";
public async Task<string> GetClassAsync()=> (await authenticationState).User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "" : "hide";
    
protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    MyClassProp = await GetClassAsync(); // also call GetClass in OnInitializedAsync
    StateHasChanged();
    await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
}
```

The `IsAuthenticated` property that I have been created in the question is always equals to its initial state and does not change with `AuthenticationState` being changed even if I reset its value in `OnParametersSetAsync`. Calling `StateHasChanged()` in Login and Logout methods is not necessary. If instead of using `MyClassProp` property, I call `GetClassAsync` from the markup, it does not work either.

**Warning:** The whole approach of hiding an element by setting a `css` class for unauthorized user have security issues, because the content still can be exposed or modified by user even by just using their browser.